# Why does SetSystemTime() behave differently in the Afternoons?

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-10

I wrote the below class to change the Systems date time but I can't understand why it functions differently at different times in the day:

- Mornings: The exact time passed to `SetTime()` gets set as the system time.
- Afternoons: The time passed to `SetTime()` +1Hr gets set as the system time, where does the additional one hour come from?

.

```
public class SystemDateTimeController
{        

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetSystemTime", SetLastError = true)]
private extern static bool Win32SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME sysTime);       


    private struct SYSTEMTIME
    {
        public ushort wYear;
        public ushort wMonth;
        public ushort wDayOfWeek;
        public ushort wDay;
        public ushort wHour;
        public ushort wMinute;
        public ushort wSecond;
        public ushort wMilliseconds;
    }

    public static void SetTime(DateTime NewDateTime)
    {
        try
        {
            SYSTEMTIME systime = new SYSTEMTIME();

            systime.wMilliseconds = (ushort)NewDateTime.Millisecond;
            systime.wSecond = (ushort)NewDateTime.Second;
            systime.wMinute = (ushort)NewDateTime.Minute;
            systime.wHour = (ushort)NewDateTime.Hour;

            systime.wDayOfWeek = (ushort)NewDateTime.DayOfWeek;

            systime.wDay = (ushort)NewDateTime.Day;
            systime.wMonth = (ushort)NewDateTime.Month;
            systime.wYear = (ushort)NewDateTime.Year;

            Win32SetSystemTime(ref systime);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log("Failed to set system date time to: " + NewDateTime.ToString() + ". Exception: " + e.ToString());
        }

    }

}
```

I know the exact time passed to `SetTime()` and for testing purpouses and to eliminate any possibilities to do with the source I have even passed a hardcoded string: `Convert.ToDateTime("07/06/2018 13:00:00");`

Comment: We have no idea, what your code does. The code you've shown works as expected. Presumably, your input is in local time, but `SetSystemTime` expects UTC. We cannot see the code that's broken. Show a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable It was local DateTime that I was trying to set, I assumed that the method takes the DateTime as it is and sets it as the system time without caring whether it UTC or Local Time based. Obviously I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetSystemTime expects UTC. The OP is feeding it local time, thats the problem (Thanks to [@IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable))

For your purpose better use [SetLocalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
which uses always your local timezone.

Greetings

Comment: `SetSystemTime` doesn't mess with time zones. It expects UTC. The OP is feeding it local time, as their hardcoded string shows.

Comment: @IInspectable This makes sens now, Thanks.

Comment: `SetLocalTime` has the precise same issue. You pass it UTC, and all bets are off. If your method takes a [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2), evaluate its [Kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind?view=netframework-4.7.2) property, and call the appropriate API, or apply the required adjustments manually.